# how to download unity 7.3?

Tags: 14.04, unity

I just noticed that Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) ships unity 7.3 and it looks promising because of the transparent top bar thingy. I want it on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS because I don't want to install Vivid on my computer right now (considering it's a beta) and I want to check some things out before I go burn the beta .iso.

Comment: you mean how to install unity 7.3 on 14.04, not download

Answer (score 2):

You do not install core Ubuntu+1 software in a current release. For something like VLC you could install from source or a 3rd party bleeding edge PPA but if you want to test something as Unity 7.3 you need to install vivid in virtual box or vmware.

Installing Unity 7.3 into a current release will pull in every bit of software that is Vivid. Effectively making your system Vivid.

I also assume you meant to install it and not download.

If you do actually want to download it you can from the [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/unity/7.3). Or directly version [7.3.2](https://launchpad.net/unity/7.3/7.3.2/+download/unity-7.3.2.tar.bz2) (md5: 7e9d53d4bc84314d068113e8c981b9aa unity-7.3.2.tar.bz2)

Comment: I'm actually noob at tars but if you could actually  make a step-by-step process i could do it because mainly my Ubuntu distro is Trusty and I believe the LTS enablement stack ran linux 3.19 rc1 in working order and I think it'll work on 7.3.2